# Hibernate: Native SQL query repeating column results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm experiencing some strange issues when executing the following native SQL query within a Hibernate environment:

```
public List<Object[]> getExcelResults(Integer idSurvey)
{
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();

    //build query string
    queryString.append("select s.idSection, s.description as sectionDescription, ");
    queryString.append("q.idQuestion, q.description as questionDescription, q.type, ");
    queryString.append("a.idAnswer, a.description, ");
    queryString.append("sum(sa.checked), avg(sa.value), count(sl.idSurveyLog) ");
    queryString.append("from surveylog sl ");
    queryString.append("inner join surveyanswerlog sa ");
    queryString.append("on sl.idSurveyLog = sa.idSurveyLog ");
    queryString.append("inner join answer a ");
    queryString.append("on sa.idAnswer = a.idAnswer ");
    queryString.append("inner join question q ");
    queryString.append("on a.idQuestion = q.idQuestion ");
    queryString.append("inner join section s ");
    queryString.append("on q.idSection = s.idSection ");
    queryString.append("where sl.idSurvey = :idSurvey ");
    queryString.append("group by s.idSection, q.idQuestion, a.idAnswer ");
    queryString.append("order by s.idSection, q.idQuestion, a.idAnswer asc; ");

    //create query
    Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString.toString());
    query.setInteger("idSurvey", idSurvey);

    return query.list();
}
```

If you look at the properties that are being returned, you'll notice that there are three `description` fields from three different tables. The problem that I'm having is that the value of the column `a.description` is being duplicated in the array positions that should correspond to `s.description` and `q.description`.

For example, if I had a result row such as:

`[1, "Section A", 1, "Question A", 1, 1, "Answer A", 2, 2, 2]`

Hibernate would return an incorrect `Object[]` for that row such as:

`[1, "Answer A", 1, "Answer A", 1, 1, "Answer A", 2, 2, 2]`

At first I thought that I needed to use aliases since all of those columns have the same names, but as you can see from the code above, `a.description` doesn't have an alias. The reason for this is that, if I add an alias to all three columns, I get a sqlexception which reads *Column "description" not found*. I'm completely stumped, it is as if the code were mocking me.

Even weirder, if I take the generated SQL query from the console and run on it on MySQL it works fine. I suspect that I might have some sort of typo, but I've been looking at this code for so long that I no longer see anything.

Comment: Just a note: using + to concatenate the sections of you query would be more readable, and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `addScalar` method for all the query projections. For example,

```
  Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString.toString())
    .addScalar("sectionDescription", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
    .addScalar("questionDescription", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
    .setInteger("idSurvey", idSurvey);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was testing this but for some reason I can't find a reference to StandardBasicTypes. Do you know which Jar this is on or another way to set that type?

Comment: `org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes`. It is in the core jar file `hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar`. Maybe you are using a very old version?

Comment: I'm using version 3. I'll look for the equivalent for that version. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, that was it. The hibernate 3 equivalent for that constant is Hibernate.STRING